# How to get the exit code of a Boost process?

Tags: c++, boost, signals

I wondering, how to get the exit code of my child process. The function exit_code() always return 0, doesn't matter terminated (send SIGKILL) or correctly finished.

I am using boost ver 1.65 and C++0x. I cant change these settings.

As I read in the documentation:

> int exit_code() const;
>
> Get the exit_code. The return value is without any meaning if the child wasn't waited for or if it was terminated.

So this function is not helping me, but I may could use the error code.

```
std::error_code ec;
bp::system("g++ main.cpp", ec);
```

But std::error_code is only supported since c++11. I tried boost::system::error_code, but thats not correct.

Here the link to Boost::process:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/boost_process/tutorial.html

Any idea, how to get that exit code?

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile. `bp::system` is a function, not a type.

Comment: I am sorry, copy/paste mistake. I fixed it.

Comment: There are many ways to do that in Boost Process. However it seems you're just mixing up documentation for `child` and `system` (among others?)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the exit code simply by checking the return value:

```
int ec = bp::system("g++ main.cpp");
```

The overload taking an `std::error_code` is only for handling the edge case of `g++` not existing in the first place (so it can never start the executable, and therefore there is no exit code). If you do not use that function, it will throw an exception on failure instead.<sup>1</sup>

```
try {
    int ec = bp::system("g++ main.cpp");
    // Do something with ec
} catch (bp::process_error& exception) {
    // g++ doesn't exist at all
}
```

A cleaner way to do this would be to resolve `g++` yourself first by searching the `$PATH` environment variable (just like your shell would):

```
auto binary_path = bp::search_path(`g++`);
if (binary_path.empty()) {
    // g++ doesn't exist
} else {
    int ec = bp::system(binary_path, "main.cpp");
}
```

<sup><sup>1</sup> Note, however, that C++0x *is* C++11, just before it was formally standardized, and that it is very likely your standard library will support `std::error_code` even if you tell it to use C++0x.</sup>